# How do I load a DIV only when I click a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><div id="tickets"><a href="#"  role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">My Tickets</a></div></li>
  <li class="active"><div id="approvals"><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Approvals</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

The above Approvals tab is connected to a `div` so I want the `div` to load only when the user clicks on this tab:

[image]

I don't want the div to load when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$("#approvals").click(function() {
  $('#your_div_id').html('<div> Hello World </div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:none` on the div that you don't want to appear on page load.

Then, bind a click handler to the approvals div:

```
$("#approvals").click(function() {
  $("#approvals_div").show();
});
```

Your markup might look something like this:

```js
$("#approvals").click(function(){
  $("#approvals_div").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li class="active"><div id="tickets"><a href="#"  role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">My Tickets</a></div></li>
   <li class="active"><div id="approvals"><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Approvals</a></div></li>
</ul>
    
 <div id="approvals_div" style="display:none;">
   I'm initially hidden!
 </div>
```